# PHP mail function with jQuery / AJAX and Google ReCaptcha

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email, recaptcha

I'm need to send mail with PHP, through a HTML form with Google Recaptcha; once the mail has been sent, a message appears where the form was (this is done with jQuery).

If I delete all Recaptcha-related code, the mail is sent and jQuery works fine. This is the code in index.php:

```
 <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#mail").click(function() {
                    $.post("form.php",
                        {
                            message: document.myForm.message.value,
                            from: document.myForm.from.value,
                            email: document.myForm.email.value,
                        },
                        function(data,status) {
                            $("#form").hide(1000);
                            $("button").hide(1000);
                            $(".tp_contact_left").html(data);
                        }
                    );
                });
            });

        </script>

        <!-- Formulario -->
        <span class="tp_contact_left">

            <form name="myForm" id="form" method="post" action="" />

                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="Tu nombre" required><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Tu e-mail" required><br>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40" required draggable="false" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu mensaje"></textarea><br>
                    <input type="reset" value="Delete">
                </fieldset>

            </form>

            <button id="mail">Send</button>

        </span>
```

And in form.php:

```
 $to = 'yourmail@domain.com';
 $subject = 'Contact';

 $message = 'Text content<br /><br />'
. 'Nombre: '
. $_POST["from"]
. '<br />Email: '
. $_POST["email"]
. '<br />Mensaje: '
. $_POST["message"];

 $headers = 'From: mail@domain.com' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

 if (!mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Error.';
}
else {
    echo 'Thanks. Message sent.';
}
```

But when I add the ReCaptcha code, I don't know where to put the g-recaptcha-response variable when using jQuery post method. With `grecaptcha.getResponse()` I get the json response, but I'm not being able to send the post request to form.php. Moreover, nothing before `$response = grecaptcha.getResponse();` is beign executed:

```
 <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#mail").click(function() {
                    // New line
                    $response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
                    alert($response);
                    $.post("form.php",
                        {
                            message: document.myForm.message.value,
                            from: document.myForm.from.value,
                            email: document.myForm.email.value,
                            // Modified line
                            grecaptcharesponse: $response
                        },
                        function(data,status) {
                            $("#form").hide(1000);
                            $("button").hide(1000);
                            $(".tp_contacto_left").html(data);
                        }
                    );
                });
            });

        </script>

 <span class="tp_contact_left">

            <form name="myForm" id="form" method="post" action="" />

                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="Tu nombre" required><br>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Tu e-mail" required><br>
                    <textarea name="message" rows="15" cols="40" required draggable="false" placeholder="Escribe aquí tu mensaje"></textarea><br>
                    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekey"></div>
                    <input type="reset" value="Borrar">
                    <input id="mail" name="enviar_mail" type="submit" value="Enviar">
                </fieldset>

            </form>

        </span>
```

The code in form.php is:

```
 <?php

if (isset ($_POST['grecaptcharesponse'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['grecaptcharesponse'];
}

if (!$captcha) {
    echo 'Por favor, haz click en el checkbox';
    exit;
}

$to = 'mail@mail.com';
$subject = 'Formulario de contacto';

$message = 'Nuevo mensaje recibido desde el formulario de la web<br /><br />'
    . 'Nombre: '
    . $_POST["from"]
    . '<br />Email: '
    . $_POST["email"]
    . '<br />Mensaje: '
    . $_POST["message"];

$headers = 'From: Formulario web <mail@mail.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

$response = file_get_contents ("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEY&response="
    . $captcha . "&remoteip="
    . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$result = json_decode ($response);

if (!$result->success) {
    echo 'Spam';
    exit;
}

if (!mail ($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo 'Error en el envío.';
}
else {
    echo 'Gracias por contactar con nosotros.';
}

?>
```

Is there some way to send the g-recaptcha-response data to the jQuery post method?

Answer (score 0):

grecaptcha.getResponse() will give you the user's response.

Moreover, $response.success will give error because:

1. It is not the correct syntax. This is PHP, so the correct syntax is:
   $response -> success.
2. The server's response is a json string, not an object.

You need to decode the json string into an object; json_decode($response); should do the trick.
Now you can use $response -> success to verify the captcha.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @user3847106, you were right with the syntax... I'm now able to decode the response, and process the recaptcha correctly.But when I try to pass grecaptcha.getResponse() to the .post() jQuery function it just doesn't work. See the modified code above.